# Schedule deletion of object in Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, background, parse-cloud-code

I want to schedule the deletion of an object in Parse a certain time after the object is made (automatically), but I am new to cloud code, and I have not found anything with background jobs that can do the job. I am programming my app in Swift. Does anyone know if this is possible, or is it a stupid question?

Any example code would be appreciated! :D

Comment: I think it is kind of stupid to "schedule" this kind of job, isnt there a better way how to do it on some demand (like when user log outs, or something like that)..... It is possible to do it in cloud code, but you have to trigger the cloud code at some point. I thin it might be possible with background jobs too but they are not supported on open source parse server at this momment...